# Disable/configure Back & Forward (History Scroll) through Shift + Mouse Wheel in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, internet-explorer

I have a problem with Internet Explorer.

Sometimes (not always) when you use the mouse wheel to scroll a page up/down it instead chooses to go back or forth in the web browsing history. This behavior is the same as when you hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key simultaneously using the wheel.

My guess is that Internet Explorer somehow gets misled by something and thinks that I'm actually pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This is in turn maybe an artifact of the fact that this particular session is a remote-desktop session originating from Linux (Ubuntu).

Needless to say the problem can be quite irritating and the alternative of completely turning off the wheel functionality doesn't seem like an option as other applications would suffer greatly from this.

Anyway back to my question(s):

1. Is it possible to map the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Mouse Wheel to a simple wheel event for Internet Explorer?
2. Is it possible to disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Mouse Wheel event for Internet Explorer?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) scripts.

1. Map the shift+wheel to simple wheel events in Internet Explorer

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class IEFrame

$+WheelUp::   Send {WheelUp}
$+WheelDown:: Send {WheelDown}
```

2. Disable the shift+wheel events in Internet Exlorer

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class IEFrame

+WheelUp::   return
+WheelDown:: return
```